# Can we get better contrast on the .question-status boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Right now `.question-status` is a rather tough to read pale orange on light gray.

Windows 8, IE10, 125% zoom (because large monitor):

[image: rendering]

Chrome 29, Ubuntu 13.04, 125% zoom: (nevermind the black border courtesy of `scrot`)

[image: rendering]

If we want to get an objective unit of measure, [Contrast-A](http://www.dasplankton.de/ContrastA/) says `#EEEEEE` and `#DC9714` fails the Web Content Accessibilty Guidelines (WCAG 2.0) by getting a Luminance Constrast Ratio of 2.13 when 4.5 would be better. I'm not saying we need to abide to WCAG 2.0, I'm just saying it's probably not my monitor, or my eyes, being messed up :)

Can we get something that stands out a little more? Even if it's just a [drop-shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME5Y3.png) or [`text-transform: freehanded-circle`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xoXc.png) or what have you?

Comment: I disagree that this is tough to read.

Comment: I will start using `text-transform: freehanded-circle` in everything I do now.

Comment: I don't think it's *that* bad. Monitor settings may be a factor for you, @badp.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's by no means _unreadable,_ I've been standing it for months, but usually I pay it little mind it anyway because I already sort of know what that field says anyway. I think it stands to improvement considered how large and complex those fields have become in the meantime, with bulleted lists and whatnot.

Comment: I find that text hard to read on any of my monitors.

Comment: I find it quite unpleasant to read, I have to squint.

Comment: I also find it somewhat difficult to read. I find that using a black text-shadow works well in situations like these for improving readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - This was fixed a while ago. Status boxes are now a *much* more readable black text on yellow-ish background:

[image: Close Reason Box for Primarily Opinion Based]